# Is this a good fit for a class or struct (speed is more important than memory)?

Tags: c#, .net, class, struct

Normally, I'd never have to ask myself whether a given scenario is better suited to a struct or class and frankly I did not ask that question before going the class way in this case. Now that I'm optimizing, things are getting a little confusing.

I'm writing a number crunching application that deals with extremely large numbers containing millions of Base10 digits. The numbers are (x,y) coordinates in 2D space. The main algorithm is pretty sequential and has no more than 200 instances of the class `Cell` (listed below) in memory at any given time. Each instance of the class takes up approximately 5MB of memory resulting in no more than 1GB in total peak memory for the application. The finished product will run on a 16 core machine with 20GB of RAM and no other applications hogging up the resources.

Here is the class:

```
// Inheritance is convenient but not absolutely necessary here.
public sealed class Cell: CellBase
{
    // Will contain numbers with millions of digits (512KB on average).
    public System.Numerics.BigInteger X = 0;
    // Will contain numbers with millions of digits (512KB on average).
    public System.Numerics.BigInteger Y = 0;

    public double XLogD = 0D;
    // Size of the array is roughly Base2Log(this.X).
    public byte [] XBytes = null;

    public double YLogD = 0D;
    // Size of the array is roughly Base2Log(this.Y).
    public byte [] YBytes = null;

    // Tons of other properties for scientific calculations on X and Y.
    // NOTE: 90% of the other fields and properties are structs (similar to BigInteger).

    public Cell (System.Numerics.BigInteger x, System.Numerics.BigInteger y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.XLogD = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Log(x, 2);
        this.XBytes = x.ToByteArray();

        this.Y = y;
        this.YLogD = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Log(y, 2);
        this.YBytes = y.ToByteArray();
    }
}
```

I chose to use a class instead of a struct simply because it 'felt' more natural. The number of fields, methods and memory all instinctively pointed to classes as opposed to structs. I further justified that by considering how much overhead temporary assignment calls would have since the underlying primary objects are instances of BigInteger, which itself is a struct.

The question is, have I chosen wisely here considering speed efficiency is the ultimate goal in this case?

Here's a bit about the algorithm in case it helps. In each iteration:

1. Sorting performed once on all 200 instances. 20% of execution time.
2. Calculating neighboring (x,y) coordinates of interest. 60% of execution time.
3. Parallel/Threading overhead for point 2 above. 10% of execution time.
4. Branching overhead. 10% of execution time.
5. The most expensive function: BigInteger.ToByteArray() [(implementation)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11819552/938668).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell based on what you've written (we don't know how often you end up copying a value of type `Cell` for example) but I would *strongly* expect a `class` to be the correct approach here.

The number of *methods* in the class is irrelevant, but if it has lots of fields you need to consider the impact of copying all those fields any time you pass a value to another method (etc).

Fundamentally it doesn't *feel* like a value type to start with - but I understand that if performance is particularly important, the philosophical aspects may not be as interesting to you.

So yes, I think you've made the right decision, and I see no reason to believe anything else at the moment - but of course if you can easily change the decision and *test* it as a struct, that would be better than guesswork. Performance is remarkably difficult to predict accurately.

Comment: Correct. 200 instances of this type make for a ridiculously low heap overhead compared to a total of 1GB.

Comment: Regarding assignment, there aren't too many explicit cases but, consider the constructor. It takes two BigInteger arguments which are structs. That is expensive (or is it?). Similarly, so do a lot of other functions within the class. I wonder why MS decided to keep the BigInteger a struct. I would have loved to inject code to BigInt at runtime to access underlying data but can't do that for a production application.

Comment: @RaheelKhan: I suspect `BigInteger` uses an array (or other class) under the covers, as a field - otherwise it couldn't cope with an arbitrary size of data, could it?

Comment: Yes, it definitely uses an internal array. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11819552/938668) is the ToByteArray implementation. I guess that means the fact that BigInteger is a struct is not really a bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you for the last suggestion in your answer by the way. I was subconsciously avoiding refatoring to a struct but you're right, nothing speaks louder than results.

Answer (score 4):

This would be better fit as a class, for many reasons, including

- It doesn't logically represent a single value
- It's larger than 16 bytes
- It's mutable

For details, see [Choosing Between Classes and Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

In addition, I'd also suggest that it's better suited to a class given:

- It contains reference types (arrays).  Structures containing classes are rarely a good design idea.

This is especially true, though, given what you're doing.  If you were to use a `struct`, sorting would require copies of the entire struct, instead of just copies of the references.  Method calls (unless passed by ref) would incur a huge overhead, as well, since you'd be copying all of the data.

Parallelization of items in a collection could also likely incur huge overhead, as the bounds checking on any array of the struct (ie: if it's kept in a `List<Cell>` or similar) would cause bad false sharing, since all access into the list would access the memory at the start of the list.

I would recommend leaving this as a class, and, in addition, I would suggest trying to move the fields into properties, and making the class as immutable as possible.  This will help keep your design clean, and less likely to be problematic when multithreading.

Comment: Mutability is probably not a concern here as he is seriously aiming at performance. I think design issues are not important right now.

Comment: @usr Design issues tend to be key to performance, though - clean designs (esp. immutability) are critical if you want to be able to refactor multi-threaded code in the optimization phases.  It's almost impossible to optimize (well) badly designed code.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, I appreciate your emphasis on design but the actual complexity of the algorithm in terms of LOC and branching is surprisingly simple. In fact, by the time I am done with optimizations, the application will contain only 10% of the methods it does now. So yes, speed is key here.

Comment: @RaheelKhan In this case, the two likely go hand in hand, though.  But yes, with that put aside, a class is still likely the best option.  You mention sorting - what type of collection is holding the 200 Cells?

Comment: The good old Generic.List<Cell> with a custom Generic.Comparer<Cell>. I wonder why you asked that. I mean, do you think I've overlooked something here?

Comment: @RaheelKhan `List<T>` uses an array internally.  When you're performing the work in parallel on the items, lookups by index internally use array lookups, which in turn all lookup a value stored just before the start of the array (for bounds checking).  This can cause false sharing - it's a good idea to avoid that, and just stick to the references, so you get 1) Good cache coherency and 2) avoid false sharing.

Comment: Thank you. That's a solid consideration. A little off-topic but I do use thread-local versions of Parallel.For but without custom partitioning. Would you recommend another strategy here?

Comment: @RaheelKhan That would likely be fine, if you're using classes - with structs, though, it can be problematic potentially.

Comment: I'd agree on mutability. Of the pros and cons of immutability, many impact seriously upon performance, so it is not irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Since your class does contain arrays which do consume most of your memory and you have only 200 Cell Instances around the memory consumption of the class itself is not an issue. You were right that a class felt more natural it is indeed the right choice. My guess would be that the comparison of XByte[] and XYBytes[] does limit your sorting time. It all depends how big your arrays are and how you do perform the comparison.

Comment: The byte arrays are a pain yes. They only exist to avoid calling BigInteger.ToByteArray() repeatedly. And the size of the arrays are of course base 2 log of x and y.

Comment: It might be worth wrapping the use of those byte-arrays in such a way that you can quickly change it with just calling `ToByteArray` repeatedly. Then you can test if the memory cost truly saves on the cost of those repeated calls, and indeed test again later on (as changes to the application change the balance of call frequency to memory use).

Answer (score 1):

Let's start ignoring the performance matters, and work up to them.

Structs are ValueTypes and ValueTypes are value-types. Integer's and `DateTime`'s are value-types and a good comparison. There's no sense in talking about how one `1` is or isn't the same as `1`, or how one `2010-02-03T12:45:23.321Z` is or isn't the same as another `2010-02-03T12:45:23.321Z`. They may have different significance in different uses, but that 1 == 1 and 1 != 2 and that 2010-02-03T12:45:23.321Z == 2010-02-03T12:45:23.321Z and 2010-02-03T12:45:23.321Z != 2931-03-05T09:21:29.43Z is inherent to the nature of integers and date-times and that's what makes them value-types.

That's the purest way of thinking about this. If it matches the above it's a value-type, if it doesn't, it's a reference type. Nothing else comes into it.

Extension 1: If an X can have an X then it has to be a reference type. Whether this logically follows from what was said above is debatable, but whatever you think on the matter you can't have a struct that has an instance of another one of itself as a member (directly or indirectly) in practice, so that's that.

Extension 2: Some say that the difficulties that come from mutable structs come from the above, and some do not. Again though, whatever you think on the matter, there are practical difficulties. A mutable struct can be useful in a few cases, but they cause enough confusion that they should be restricted to private cases as an optimisation rather than public cases as a matter of course.

**Here comes the performance bit...**

Value types and reference types have different characteristics in different cases that affects the speed, the memory use, and the way that memory use affects garbage collection in several ways giving each different pros and cons as far as performance goes. Just how much attention we pay to that, depends on how much we need to get down to that level. It's worth saying right now that the ways in which they differ tends to balance to a win if you follow the above rule on deciding between struct and class so if we start thinking about this beyond that, we're at least bordering on optimisation territory.

Optimisation level 1.

If a value type instance will contain more than 16bytes per instance, it should probably be made a reference. This is sometimes even stated as a "natural" difference rather than one of optimisation. Strictly there's nothing in "value type" that entails "16 or fewer bytes" but it does tend to balance out that way.

Moving away from the simplistic "16 bytes" rule, the smaller it is the faster it is to copy, and contrary-wise, so bending it for a 20-byte instance is of less impact than bending it for a 200-byte instance.

Will you need to box and unbox a lot? Since the introduction of generics we've been able to avoid a lot of cases where we would box and unbox with 1.0 and 1.1, so this isn't as big a deal as once, but if you do it will hurt performance.

Optimisation level 2.

The fact that value types can be place on a stack, placed directly in an array (rather than references to them) and be direct fields of a struct or class (again, rather than references to them) can make access to them and to their fields faster.

If you're going to create an array of them **and** if all-zero values are a useful starting point for you, you get that immediately, where as with reference types you get an array of nulls. This can make structs faster.

**Edit:** Something that extends from the above, if you are going to be iterating through arrays rapidly, then as well as the direct-access giving a boost over following the reference, you'll be loading a couple of instances into CPU cache at a time (64 bytes worth on current x86-32 or x86-64/amd, 128 bytes worth on ia-64). It has to be a pretty tight loop to matter, but there are cases where it does.

Pretty much most "I went for struct rather than class for performance" comes down to either the first point, or the first in combination with the second.

Optimisation level 3.

If you will have cases where some of the values you are concerned with are duplicates of each other, and they are large in size, then with immutable instances (or mutable instances you simply never mutate once you start doing what follows), you can deliberately alias different references so that you save a lot of memory because your e.g. 20 duplicate objects of 2kiB in size are actually the same object, hence saving 26kiB in that case. It can also make comparisons faster because the cases where you can short-cut on identity are more frequent. This can only be done with reference types.

Optimisation level 4.

Structs that have arrays do though alias the contained array and could internally use the above technique, balancing out that point, though it's somewhat more involved.

Optimisation level X.

It doesn't matter how much thinking about these pros and cons comes to a particular answer, if actually measuring the results comes to a different ones. Since there are both pros and cons, it's always possible to get this wrong.

In thinking about 1 through 4, along with the differences between value and reference types aside from such optimisation concerns, I think you should go for a class.

In thinking about level X I wouldn't be amazed if your actually testing it proved me wrong. The best bit is, if it is arduous to change from class to struct (you make heavy use of aliasing or the possibility of null value), then you can be pretty confident that doing so is a lose. If it isn't arduous, then you can just do so and measure! I'd strongly suggest measuring a test that involves a real run over doing something 10,000 times - who cares if you can do a given operation 10,000 times in a few less seconds if you do a different operation 20 times more often in the real thing?

Comment: Well said and thank you. This is definitely a reference answer for the 'class vs struct' question and should be given higher visibility on this page. Jon Skeet beat you to the answer but I bet he would agree.

Comment: I was thinking of refactoring to pass all struct method parameters by reference but re-reading some of the points above tells me that won't do much good either. Take the constructor for example, It takes two structs that total 1MB in internal array size but the struct heap only stores references to the arrays so boxing (by reference) won't do much good there.

Comment: No, boxing will only save you 8 bytes of copying at that point, and you've added the cost of boxing and later unboxing. `BigInterval` is in itself a good example of some of the points above: Its size is 8 or 12 bytes (32/64bit versions), but the array that can be much larger is a reference type. The immutability lets the array be safely referenced between different copies of the same integer, so saving memory. Looking at my optimisation levels above, it has the best of both worlds, in being a small immutable struct that references a large reference type....

Comment: ... but note that if we only paid attention to the "Let's start ignoring the performance matters" bit, we'd probably go for struct in that case too. After all, the design decisions that went into .NET itself were made both encoding the value/reference distinction into the type system (C++ for example has the distinction quite separate from types, which is a plus in some ways but increases complexity in others) and considering how they'd be treated. Most of the time, "natural" structs and "natural" classes are more efficient when built as such rather than their opposite.

Comment: Agreed. I started out with a huge list of potential optimizations and as I dive in to apply each one, the efficiency of 'natural' design renders it pointless. By this time, I am left with only a handful of things to improve down from a list of hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

A struct can only contain an array-type field safely if either (1) the state of the struct depends upon the identity of the array rather than its contents (as is the case with `ArraySegment`), or (2) no reference to the array will ever be held by anything that might try to mutate it (typically, this means that the array field will be private, and the struct itself will create the array and perform all modifications that will ever be done to it, before storing a reference in the field).

I advocate using structs much more commonly than other people here, but the fact that your data storage thingie would have two array-type fields would seem a strong argument against using a struct.