# BigInteger source code

Tags: c#, biginteger

I'm trying to make a fast Fibonacci algorithm. It often needs to assign a BigInteger to another variable and because the C# BigInteger is implemented as a struct, it needs to copy the entire array, which can be thousands of integers. So I need a BigInteger implementation that can be acessed by reference. Both .Net Reflector and ILSpy only show empty implementations.

In any case it'd be interesting to see the source code, as asked here:
[How does the BigInteger store values internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819436/how-does-the-biginteger-store-values-internally)

The problem is that every so called source code file does not actually have an implementation, dll's and downloaded from:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Making a wrapper class won't help, because the algorithm requires much calculation and even a simple addition requires three copies of the entire array.

Does anyone know why BigInteger is implemented as a struct? And where the source code can be found?

Comment: `BigInteger` is implemented as a struct so that it has value semantics rather than reference semantics.

Comment: A BigInteger has two instance fields, `int _sign` and `uint[] _bits`. That means a copy of the struct refers to the same array, so the problem you describe does not exist.

Comment: A thanks, din't think of that.

Comment: Also, I have an implementation of the Matrix Form of Fibonacci somewhere, would you be interested in that?

Comment: The array is copied by reference; copying a large BigInteger is very fast. Which you would know *if you had measured the performance before you asked a question about it*.  **Measure first** when you have a performance question.  Now, additions do make copies because the result is *a different number*. When you add two to six, you don't magically turn six into eight. You end up with three numbers: two, six and eight.

Comment: @EricLippert I did measure the performance, and only assigning new values was barely any faster than addition, I thought the difference was caused by the fact that addition increases the array size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a faster implementation; I would recommend that you take a look at an alternative implementation; such as the [GNU Multi-Precision Library](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/) wrapper.

You could also take a look at this implementation of [BigInt](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36323/BigInt).

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is eight years old, but I want to clear something up here for anyone reading this in the future because this question is caused by and could lead to a massive misconception about structs.

The question states the following:

> because the C# BigInteger is implemented as a struct, it needs to copy the entire array

This is absolutely incorrect. Yes, it is true that all values stored within a struct instance are copied when assigning the instance to anything. However, this does not mean that, in the case of `BigInteger`, the entire array is copied when that happens. The only thing copied is the **reference** to that array, which is just like copying a single int value (I think the exact size of an object reference is machine dependent, but the idea remains the same). This is always the case when storing instances of reference types (classes) in a struct. Objects themselves are never copied, only the references to them.

So the very problem that lead to this question doesn't actually exist, so there's no reason to worry about massive performance issues caused by array copying and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

The full source code of BigInteger and entire .net core is now eventually available on [source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/#System.Runtime.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,035eb7acfa6585a0) and [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/master/src/libraries/System.Runtime.Numerics/src/System/Numerics).