# Is it possible to use one variable to represent numbers of unlimited length in programming?

Tags: variables, language-agnostic, numbers

I've been using C# for three years to make games and I've played with various simulations where numbers sometimes get big and `Int32` is not enough to store the value. Eventually even `Int64` became insufficient for my experiments, it took several such fields (actually an array of variable length) and a special property to correctly handle such big numbers. And so I wondered: Is there a way to declare a numeric variable with unlimited (unknown beforehand) length so I can relax and let the computer do the math?

We can write any kind of number we like on paper without needing any special kind of paper. We can also type a lot of words in a text file without needing special file system alterations to make it save and load correctly. Isn't there a variable to declare a who-knows-how-long-it-will-be number in any programming languages?

Comment: `Int64` insufficient? Wow. Java has `BigInteger`, which basically is a list of integers that can grow infinitely. I'm not sure if C# has the same struct.

Comment: It's not specifically about C#, I'm asking about other programming languages, and if there exists such a solution in any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern dynamic languages such as Perl6, Tcl8 and Ruby goes one step further by allowing you to store unlimited (up to available RAM) sized numbers in number types.

Most of these languages don't have separate integer and floating point types but rather a single "number" type that automatically gets converted to whatever it needs to be to be stored in RAM. Some, like Perl6, even includes complex numbers in its "number" type.

How it's implemented at the machine level is that by default numbers are assumed to be integers - so int32 or int64. If need be numbers are converted to floats or doubles if the result of a calculation or assignment isn't an integer. If the integer grows too large then the interpreter/runtime environment silently converts it to a bigInt object/struct (which is simply a big, growable array or linked-list of ints).

How it appears to the programmer is that numbers have unlimited size (again, up to available RAM).

Still, there are gotchas with this system (kind of like the 0.1+0.2!=0.3 issue with floats) so you'd still need to be aware of the underlying implementation even if you can ignore it 99.99% of the time.

For example, if at any point in time you super large number gets converted to a floating point number (most likely a double in hardware) you'll lose precision. Because that's just how floating point numbers work. Sometimes you can do it accidentally. In some languages for example, the power function (like `pow()` in C) returns a floating point result. So raising an integer to the power of another integer may truncate the result if it's too large.

For the most part, it works. And I personally feel that this is the sane way of dealing with numbers. Lots of language designers have apparently come up with this solution independently.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with .NET 4, the .NET framework contains a [BigInteger structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx), which can handle integers of arbitrary size.

Since your question is language-agnostic, it might be worth to mention that *internally* BigInteger stores the value in an array of unsigned integers, see the following SO question for details:

- [How does the BigInteger store values internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11819436/87698)

BigInteger is immutable, so there is no need to "resize" the array. Arithmetic operations create *new* instances of BigInteger, with appropriately sized arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to [...] represent numbers of unlimited length [...]?

No.

On existing computers it is not possible to represent unlimited numbers because the machines are finite. Even when using all existing storage it is not possible to store *unlimited* numbers.

It is possible, though, to store very large numbers. [Wikipedia has information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) on the concept of arbitrary precision integers.

Comment: You might have taken this a bit too literally. What I meant was numbers of unknown length. Or to be precise, numbers of limited, but probably great, and yet unknown at the time of declaration length.

Comment: Counter example: We can store 1/3 or sqrt(2) and perform exact arithmetic with it - look for continued fractions. While this is not what the OP had in mind, your denying claim is a bit too general.

Answer (score 1):

"Unlimited" - no, as Nikolai Ruhe soundly pointed out.  "Unknown" - yes, qualified by the first point. :}

A `BigInteger` type is available in .NET 4.0 and in Java as others point out.

For .NET 2.0+, take a look at [IntX](http://intx.codeplex.com/).

More generally, languages (or a de facto library used with them at least) generally have some support for arbitrarily long integers, which provides a means of dealing with the "unknown" you describe.

A [discussion on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-399816.html) somewhat addresses this question more generally and touches on specifics in more languages - some of which provide simpler means of leveraging arbitrarily large integers (e.g. Python and Common Lisp).  Personally, the "relax and let the computer do the math" factor was highest for me in Common Lisp years ago: so it may pay to look around broadly for perspective as you seem inclined to do.